# Reload page after button click on another page - Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I have 2 pages, one where I insert data into a Firebase database, let's call it Page2 and one where I display the Firebase Data, Page1.

I have a button click argument on Page2 where I insert data into the database but want to reload Page1 after this. It is structured like this
(Page2.xaml.cs):

```
        void btInsert_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
       //Firebase connection
       //Firebase data insertion
       //Code to reload Page1
      
    }
```

On my page 1 I have my database connection and display

Page1.xaml.cs:

```
        public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = this;
        
        var collection = firebaseClient
            .Child("Childname")
            .AsObservable<MyDatabaseRecord>()
            .Subscribe((dbevent) =>
            {
                if (dbevent != null)
                {
                    DatabaseItems.Add(dbevent.Object);
                }
            });
    }
```

Page1.xaml:

```
    <StackLayout Margin="15,0,15,5" BackgroundColor="Navy">
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding DatabaseItems}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Frame BackgroundColor="Blue" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,0,0,17" Padding="2" WidthRequest="350" CornerRadius="20">
                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Blue">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Data1}" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" FontSize="20"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Data2}" TextColor="White" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" FontSize="15"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Data3}" TextColor="White" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" FontSize="15"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Data4}" TextColor="White" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" FontSize="15"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Data5}" TextColor="White" Margin="10, 0, 0, 20" FontSize="15"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

How can I approach this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how does the user navigate from Page1 to Page2 in the first place?

Comment: @Jason Tabbed pages

Comment: I'd suggest using MessagingCenter

Comment: @Jason And how exactly would that work?

Comment: Page 1 subcribes to a "Reload" message.  Page 2 sends a "Reload" message when the data needs to be reloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this problem:

1. Using **MessagingCenter**:
   You can use `MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage>(this, "Hi");` to send.

   Then use below code to receive information:

   ```
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage> (this, "Hi", (sender) =>
    {
    // Do something whenever the "Hi" message is received
    });
   ```

   More information about **MessagingCenter** can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center
2. You can pass the collection as a parameter when the two pages are jumped and then modify the bound collection.

For arrays of data you bind, it is recommended that you use ObservableCollection to dynamically update data.

Comment: And what changes would I then need to do to my XAML code in order to add the ObservableCollection?

Comment: If you are using List ,change it to ObservableCollection. For XAMAL, you don't need to change anything.